# Bash tr: extra operand `\n'\\n\''

Tags: bash

```
Command="tr ' ' '\n' < /location/to/file.xml | sed -e '/\/Name/, $d' | grep Apple | wc -l"
New_command=`$Command`
```

The error I am getting:

> tr: extra operand `\'\\n\'' Try`tr --help' for more information.

What is wrong with what I am doing? Trying to assign a string variable to 'New_Command' so I can execute it and get the output.

Comment: Don't use strings to store code, use functions.

Comment: Not recommended: `eval "$command"`

Comment: I tested there is no **error** for me. `bash 4.3`

Comment: You should probably also be using an XML parser. In any case, it would be helpful to know exactly what you're trying to do (sample input + desired output) rather than trying to guess from your attempt.

Comment: the following command shows how arguments are splitted: `printf "'%s'\n" $Command`
this is due to different phases in command processing.
Also the pipe '|' will be interpreted as a character instead of pipe. the error message means: tr accept only two arguments first is "'" and second is "'"